# Notification sound when simulation done?

Tags: sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Customize front end to add notifications when evaluation finishes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/customize-front-end-to-add-notifications-when-evaluation-finishes)

How to setup sound alert notification when simulation is complete?

I need to do something else while waiting for a long simulation to complete instead of sitting there watching the simulation to complete the whole 'Evaluate Notebook' process.

Thank You

Comment: Look up `EmitSound[]`.

Comment: Related? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/customize-front-end-to-add-notifications-when-evaluation-finishes

Comment: I'm not sure I agree this is an exact duplicate.  The answers here wouldn't have been adequate for the supposed duplicate question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd do something like this.

```
Pause[5];
Speak["Done Pausing for 5 Seconds"]
```

Comment: In reality I'd have it say something much sexier but that's up to you :)

Comment: ...now, how do I configure *Mathematica* to use a "bedroom voice"... >:)

Comment: @J.M. Just pretend she's from Vulcan.

Comment: Hi @Andy Ross, yes please let me know how to make it smoother, possible to change pitch etc of voice?

Comment: This is what I've actually been doing recently :)

Answer (score 6):

You could set the notebook, global, or cell level option "EvaluationCompletionAction" to "Beep"

Answer (score 4):

I'd be inclined to use something like this:

```
Monitor[
  Do[Pause[0.2], {i, 50}],
  If[Mod[i, 10] == 0, Speak[ToString[2 i] <> " percent done"]]; i
]
```

Comment: This is awesome! I replaced the last `i` with a `ProgressIndicator` on a `Dynamic` counter variable, it's wonderful!