# Notification when evaluation completes

Tags: evaluation

I thought it would be fun to see a list of ways to have *Mathematica* notify you when a long evaluation completes. There are a few posts up already that address specific methods, given below, but not any open invitation to list ways one *is* or *could be* notified.

Previously mentioned methods:

[Make a noise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14761/notification-sound-when-simulation-done) (such as `Beep[]` or `Speak["All finished."]`)

[Customize the front end](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/customize-front-end-to-add-notifications-when-evaluation-finishes) (to notify using Growl)

[Send an email](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30167/automatic-e-mail-text-message-when-a-calculation-has-finished) using `SendMail[...]` that can include results in the body or as attachments.

What else do people do? I'm interested in both the practical (what people routinely use) and the fanciful.

A note to the moderators: this thread was previously closed, citing the email link as answering the question. It doesn't; it just gives details how to automatically send email. This post is about new/previously unposted methods.

Comment: Moderators: I'd like to make this a community wiki. Also feel free to give it a better tag than `evaluation`.

Comment: I just listen for the cooling fans to spin down...

Comment: @RunnyKine: Thanks for link, very neat answer there from rm-rf!

Comment: @rasher, I like your "cooling fan" method too :)

Comment: @rasher for my machine, this is quite the norm. My fans occasionally go beserk (and then add some `CUDA` stuff to make the gfx card cooling scream along). Next time I´ll go for a business machine rather than a gaming laptop :D

Comment: @GregH try getting a positive audio alert that will Ding on success and only use Beep on Failure. Here is a resource function for it.

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Ding/

Comment: @JulesManson Interesting. Thanks for resurrecting this 8-yr old, closed post!

Comment: @GregH sorry, my bad

Comment: @JulesManson I think you misunderstood me - I truly was happy to see your comment! I think about it every once in a while.