# Receive macOS notification when evaluation finishes

Tags: front-end, customization, mac-os-x

Is Mathematica able to communicate with macOS's native Notification Center in order to notify me if an evaluation finishes in any of my open notebooks?

I'm looking for a solution similar to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2193/42227) except it shouldn't rely on [Growl](http://growl.info).

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick Google search returned:

- [How can I trigger a Notification Center notification from an AppleScript or shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel)

Based on this, we can use

```
notify[asc_] := 
 RunProcess[{"osascript", "-e", 
   StringTemplate["display notification \"`message`\" with title \"`title`\""][asc]}]

notify[<|"message" -> "I'm finished!", "title" -> "Mathematica"|>]
```

You can customize this further to your needs.

Comment: I don't know. The linked thread says 10.9. It works for me on 10.12. Output is as expected.

Comment: Changing Mathematica settings is not necessary because all this does is it runs an AppleScript (see the linked post!) As for showing notifications after every evaluation: see `CellEpilog` from the thread that you yourself linked. You might try to set this in the stylesheet.

Comment: I run in macOS 10.13 `notify[asc_] := 
 RunProcess[{"osascript", "-e", 
   StringTemplate[
     "display notification \"`message`\" with title \"`title`\""][
    asc]}, "StandardOutput"]

notify[<|"message" -> "I'm finished!", "title" -> "Mathematica"|>]`, and it works in MMA 11.2. It gives me a notification.

Comment: (+1) It's too bad osascript doesn't allow you to change the icon.

Comment: @Szabolcs Please excuse my stupidity. The notifications do in fact work perfectly. I had "Do Not Disturb" enabled yesterday and had completely forgotten about it.